# How to convert Unicode string to dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, utf-8

I have a string with utf-8 encoding, like

```
>>> print s
"{u'name':u'Pradip Das'}"
```

Basically I load some data from JSON file and it loads as above.
Now, I want to covert this string in to python dictionary. So I can do like:

```
>>> print d['name']
'Pradip Das'
```

Comment: See the link posted by Dmitry Grigoryev... you can import json and use json.load() rather than reading the JSON-formatted string.

Answer (score 4):

Use EVAL to convert string to dictionary.

```
d=eval(s)
print d['name']
```

Let me know if there are any batter way to do so.

Comment: Yipee, it works for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: it's a nice quick fix solution, but you should definitely be careful throwing eval around in your code https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

a better way would be like accepted answer's ast.literal_eval

Answer (score 4):

You can use the built-in [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> a = ast.literal_eval("{'a' : '1', 'b' : '2'}")
>>> a
{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}
>>> type(a)
<type 'dict'>
```

This is safer than using `eval`.  As the docs itself recommends it:

```
>>> help(ast.literal_eval)
Help on function literal_eval in module ast:

literal_eval(node_or_string)
    Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
    expression.  The string or node provided may only consist of the following
    Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans,
    and None.
```

Additionally, you can read this [article](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) which will explain why you should avoid using `eval`.